# Beagle Bone Black PRU Device Overlay for fast IO does not work

Tags: overlay, device, beagleboneblack

I desperately try to get the PRU on my BBB working. By working I mean that I would want to use the pins P8 39-46 (GPIO2[6-13]) as a fast output controlled by the PRU.

I installed the debian for BBB (2 weeks ago, should be current) on SD.

Then I started with the following article: http://www.element14.com/community/community/designcenter/single-board-computers/next-gen_beaglebone/blog/2013/05/22/bbb--working-with-the-pru-icssprussv2

doing so, I got the PRU working with the LED example as well as with pin P8[12].

Now I try to get the other pins working. I started all over by just making a little change to the original am335x-boneblack.dtb. I just activated the PRU.
I did not change the LED heartbeat as well as pin P8.12.

Then I disabled HDMI in uEnv.txt
My "slots" look like this now:

```
0: 54:PF---
1: 55:PF---
2: 56:PF---
3: 57:PF---
4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G 
5: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI
6: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMIN,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
```

I stumbled upon this post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/JRG36bOURfk

EXACTLY what I would want to have, so I took the dts ( the second one) , compiled it, copied it to /lib/firmware and loaded it. "slots" says the overlay was loaded.

```
0: 54:PF---
1: 55:PF---
2: 56:PF---
3: 57:PF---
4: ff:P-O-L Bone-LT-eMMC-2G,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONE-EMMC-2G
5: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMI,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMI
6: ff:P-O-- Bone-Black-HDMIN,00A0,Texas Instrument,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
7: ff:P-O-L Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-PRU-IO
```

BB-PRU-IO is me.

dmesg says:

```
... part_number 'BB-PRU-IO', version 'N/A'
... slot #7: generic override
... bone: Using override eeprom data at slot 7
... slot #7: 'Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,BB-PRU-IO'
... slot #7: Requesting part number/version based 'BB-PRU-IO-00A0.dtbo
... slot #7: Requesting firmware 'BB-PRU-IO-00A0.dtbo' for board-name 'Override Board Name', version '00A0'
... slot #7: dtbo 'BB-PRU-IO-00A0.dtbo' loaded; converting to live tree
... slot #7: #2 overlays
... slot #7: Applied #2 overlays.
```

Looking good I would say.

The problem is the pinmux does not seam to be impressed:

cat pins | grep 8a4
=> pin 41 (44e108a4) 0000002f pinctrl-single

This is MODE 7 (GPIO Out). Not what I wanted. For all of pins I intended to switch to PRU Mode 5.

Now I tried the delivered dtbo's for the PRU 01,02 in /lib/firmware

*PRU-01*.dtbo seems to be a fitting example. Only the Pin is different (P9.27).
I loaded it and changed the PRU code example. 
The pins did not show the expected result:
pin 105 (44e109a4) 00000027 pinctrl-single
When I run the modified testprogram from the first articel my osci shows a flatline.

I tried *PRU-02*.dtbo. 
At least the pins showed the expected result:
pin 105 (44e109a4) 00000025 pinctrl-single
When I start my little test program I get a "bus error"

dmesg has several lines. the important ones I would say are:
    [  119.258978] WARNING: at arch/arm/mach-omap2/omap_hwmod.c:2096 _enable+0x101/0x174()
    [  119.259004] omap_hwmod: pruss: enabled state can only be entered from initialized, idle, or disabled state
    [  119.259027] Modules linked in: g_multi libcomposite btusb bluetooth rfkill uio_pruss mt7601Usta(O)
    .... several trace messages
    [  119.272382] pru-rproc 4a300000.prurproc: #8 PRU interrupts registered
    [  119.272445] pru-rproc 4a300000.prurproc: Failed to read events array
    [  119.287545] pru-rproc: probe of 4a300000.prurproc failed with error -22

PRU-02 does more than PRU-01 (what I do not understand). And it does not seem to work for me.

Now I am kind of helpless.
Any ideas on that?

EDIT:
I did what you should not do. I changed the pinmux setting in the am335x-boneblack.dtb file. I just added:
    0xA0 0x05
    0xA4 0x05
    0xA8 0x05
    0xAC 0x05
    0xB0 0x05
    0xB4 0x05
    0xB8 0x05
    0xBC 0x05

to pinmux_userled_pins {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <

Now it works, but I am not happy. I still would appreciate a regular overlay file.

Answer (score 3):

OK I got it working:

1. just enable the pruss in the am335x-boneblack.dtb (convert to dts. do the changes as described in the article mentioned in the original post)
2. Got to the website : http://kilobaser.com/blog/2014-07-28-beaglebone-black-devicetreeoverlay-generator#dtogenerator and let the site create dts files for the various pins in my case P8 46-39. Using a single DTS(DTBO) File for each individual pin works but requires 8 dtbos loaded => I moved all of them into one DTS File.

this is it:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/{
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";
    part_number = "BS_PINMODE_PRU_OUT";

    exclusive-use =
    "P8.46",
    "P8.45",
    "P8.44",
    "P8.43",
    "P8.42",
    "P8.41",
    "P8.40",
    "P8.39",
    "pr1_pru1_pru_r30_6",
    "pr1_pru_pru1_r30_7",
    "pr1_pru1_pru_r30_4",
    "pr1_pru1_pru_r30_5",
    "pr1_pru1_pru_r30_2",
    "pr1_pru1_pru_r30_3",
    "pr1_pru1_pru_r30_0",
    "pr1_pru1_pru_r30_1";

    fragment@0 {
    target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
    __overlay__ {
        bs_pinmode_pru_out: pinmux_bs_pinmode_pru_out {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <0x0a4 0x5 0x0a0 0x5 0x0ac 0x5 0x0a8 0x5 0x0b4 0x5 0x0b0 0x5 0x0bc 0x5 0x0b8 0x5>;
        };
    };
};

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        __overlay__ {
            bs_pinmode_pru_out_pinmux {
                compatible = "bone-pinmux-helper";
                status = "okay";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&bs_pinmode_pru_out>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I named the file bspm_pru_out-00A0.dts, compiled it to bspm_pru_out-00A0.dtbo and placed it it in the /lib/firmware.

You can load it via /boot/uEnv.txt or via echo... in a rc.local file... whatever you like.

Comment: Nice case! Does this all seem unnecessarily cumbersome for some seemingly basic stuff to my untrained eyes only, or did you also feel that it should somehow be more straightforward (e.g. via clearer hints for the root cause)? (Note, I'm coming from MSP430/RPi, just started stalking the BB.)

Comment: LOL... 100% true... I also regard this totally complicated. Straightforward is ... different.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Any idea why one of the resources is called `pr1_pru_pru1_r30_7` instead of  `pr1_pru1_pru_r30_7` i.e. the pru1 and pru part are switched around?

Comment: I am afraid not :-( Maybe just an error in the online tool, or somebody made a mistake correctly naming them.. you know developers :-)

Comment: I checked it again. It really looks like an error in the configurator website. For this particular pin, the MUX modes are not according to the documentation i use (Beagle Bone Pin Modes). Mode 5 should be as Mode 4 is. Mode 4 should be something like "pr1_edio_data_out 7". Why did I not notice? I do not use this pin and the dts compiler did not complain :-)